# Mysql Query Slow on large table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Trying to run the following query on a mysql table that has over 3 million rows. Its very slow to the point it pretty much hangs until the script times out. Below is the query and the explain from that query, any suggestions?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
listing_track.listingid,
listing_track.commid,
listing.listingname,
listing_package.packagename,
listing.active,
community.commname,
SUM( listing_track.impression ) AS listing_impressions,
SUM( listing_track.view ) AS listing_views,
SUM( listing_track.phone ) AS listing_phones,
SUM( listing_track.forward ) AS listing_forward,
SUM( listing_track.coupon ) AS listing_coupons,
SUM( listing_track.email ) AS listing_emails
FROM listing_track
INNER JOIN listing ON listing_track.listingid = listing.id
INNER JOIN community ON listing_track.commid = community.id
INNER JOIN listing_package ON listing.packageid = listing_package.id
WHERE listing_track.commid =2
GROUP BY listing_track.commid, listing_track.listingid, listing_track.trackip
LIMIT 0 , 25
```

Here is the explain:
[image]

Comment: Just think about it, to find the data you want it's got to check more than three million rows. Thats gonna take its time, even with the MySQL's modern algorithms.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast I understand that, but was wondering why its grabbing over a million rows when I have a limit clause. Perhaps Im not understanding mysql and how it works in that regard?

Comment: it is grabbing million rows because among other things you are using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` which gives you the number of records the query would return be there no `LIMIT` clause. Of course it should count them to know how many are there.

Comment: Did you give a shot at the "STRAIGHT_JOIN" clause I suggested below?  It ALONE makes a tremendous difference in things I've done historically... even on 14+ million record datasets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the LIMIT is applied at the end of the query, after all the costly table scans are complete. The cost is not from returning lots of rows, but instead from scanning lots of rows.

The easiest way to speed up queries like this is with a [covering index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29#Covering_Index).   This will allow you to scan through the rows you want, but require fewer bytes of I/O per row (since you're only scanning a portion of each row's data, not the entire row). Furthermore, if your index is sorted in the same way that your query is, you can avoid the cost of a sort and can scan vastly fewer rows.

Your index should have these columns below. The first three columns must be in the same order as your GROUP BY-- this allows your `GROUP BY` and `WHERE` to be vastly cheaper to execute. The second line allows the index to "cover" the query, which means that MySQL will be able to satisfy the entire listing_track part of the query from the index alone:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_listing_track_covering ON listing_track (
    commid, listingid, trackip, 
    listing_impression, listing_view, listing_phone, listing_forward, listing_coupon, listing_email);
```

With this index in place, you should be able to run the exact same query but see vastly better performance.

Comment: In `MySQL`,  `GROUP BY` also defines `ORDER BY`. This is extension to the standard.

Comment: @Quassnoi is correct - I forgot about that quirk of MySQL. I just edited my answer to remove the complaint about a missing ORDER BY.  Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: The problem is adding this index, it hangs forever when trying to add any index to the table.

Comment: MySQL index creation, if it has to swap to disk, can take a loooong time, especially on hardware with insufficient RAM or slow disks, or when MySQL is configured to be stingy with its use of RAM from the OS.  It's not impossible on a slow server for index creation ona large table to take an hour or more. Luckily you only have to create the index once.  There are index creation optimizations you can do, although they may vary across MySQL releases. I'd suggest starting your index creation and waiting an hour or two for it to complete.

Comment: ... and while you're waiting for your index to be created, you can ask another question on StackOverflow about how to optimize index creation times. Make sure to include the version of MySQL in your question, whether the table is MyISAM or InnoDB, and ideally a dump of the DDL to create your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  listing_track.listingid,
        listing_track.commid,
        listing.listingname,
        listing_package.packagename,
        listing.active,
        community.commname
        SUM( listing_track.impression ) AS listing_impressions,
        SUM( listing_track.view ) AS listing_views,
        SUM( listing_track.phone ) AS listing_phones,
        SUM( listing_track.forward ) AS listing_forward,
        SUM( listing_track.coupon ) AS listing_coupons,
        SUM( listing_track.email ) AS listing_emails
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    listing
        ORDER BY
                id
        LIMIT 25
        ) l
JOIN    listing_track lt
ON      lt.listingid = l.id
        AND lt.commid = 2
JOIN    community c
ON      c.id = lt.commid
JOIN    listing_package lp
ON      lp.packageid = l.packageid
GROUP BY
        l.id, lt.trackip
LIMIT 25
```

Create a composite index on `listing_track (listingid, commid)`

This optimization only works without `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, since the latter requires scanning all records (as if the query was run without `LIMIT` clause).

In your plan I see one more table, `account`, which is not used in the query. You need to post the whole query since even one extra table can change everything.

Comment: nested limits? Trying to get anything other than a random sample out of this query will be hard

Comment: @symcbean: yes, nested limits. Please tell what exactly is wrong with this query in your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It looks good, applicable primary keys per respective table.  I would add ONE THING...

SELECT  STRAIGHT_JOIN  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ...

This tells MySQL to do in the order you tell it.  I had similar going against gov't data of 14+ million rows linked to over 15 lookup tables (joins).  MySQL was trying to use the smaller lookup tables as the basis of joining since they were smaller and thus hung the process (I mean over 30+ hours before I killed it).  By adding STRAIGHT_JOIN since you KNOW your LISTING_TRACK is the basis of everything, and the OTHER tables are the secondary references, it should fly though that much quicker.  That being said, it will still have some work to do going over 1+ million rows in your table, but obviously more limited by your COMMID column = 2.

One other is to possibly remove your "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS" as it was noted in other searches as being "buggy", but don't know its importance for you on total records that qualified before the limit was applied.

BTW, my gov't query after adding STRAIGHT_JOIN ran in under 2 hours.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing a lot more about the structure of the data its impossible to say, however given the available informnation, the system seems to be making a reasonable attempt at the query. If you really want to process millions of rows i a single select, it is going to take time. However if the relationships are strictly 1:N you could easily drop the lookup to the other tables - and just count the records in the listng table without changing the results:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM listing
WHERE commid=2
```

What is the purpose of a query which returns a million rows?

It's possible that there's some scope for tunng the DBMS - particularly the join buffer - try running mysqltuner against it.

The plan does seem to suggest that the only filtering you've applied (listing_track.commid =2) is best served by an index lookup on the table returning in the region of a million rows - If there are only 3 million rows in the database, then a full table scan would probably be faster.

Comment: How can a query with `LIMIT 25` return a million rows?